# Como obtener el valor de una imagen que se encuentra dentro de un datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Buenas noches comunidad.

Quería hacerles una consulta, espero puedan ayudarme.
Agradezco todo tipo de ayuda de su parte.

TENGO EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
                //CODIGO CON EL QUE CREO LA COLUMNA DE TIPO IMAGEN Y AGREGO LA IMAGEN DE + AZUL Y + ROJO
                DataGridViewImageColumn imgn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgn);
                imgn.HeaderText = ""; 
                imgn.Name = "Columna1"; 
                Image image0 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\masRojo.png");
                Image image1 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\masAzul.png");
    
                
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Columna1"].Value = redimensionarImagen(image0, 15, 15);
                dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["Columna1"].Value = redimensionarImagen(image1, 15, 15);
    
            }
    
            //METODO PARA CAMBIAR DE TAMAÑO LAS IMAGENES
            private Image redimensionarImagen(Image imagen, int alto, int ancho)
            {
                var imagered = new Bitmap(alto, ancho);
                Graphics.FromImage(imagered).DrawImage(imagen, 0, 0, alto, ancho);
                Bitmap imagefi = new Bitmap(imagered);
    
                return imagefi;
            }
    
            //EVENTO DOBLE_CLICK EN LA CELDA DEL DATAGRIDVIEW
            //codigo de ejemplo
            private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "System.Drawing.Bitmap")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Selecionaste el Mas: " + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Utilizo este código para obtener el valor de la celda

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value
```

pero este me devuelve el siguiente valor

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap
```

tanto para el +Rojo como para el +Azul por lo que no se puede diferenciar, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de diferenciar los valores de estas celdas, por ejemplo que el valor del +Azul sea imagenMasAzul y para la otra celda imagenMasRojo, de manera que los haga únicos independientemente de la posición donde se encuentren dentro del datagridview.

Este es el Codigo con el que creo la columna de tipo imagen dentro del datagridview y cargo las imagenes en las celdas.

RESULTADOS:

1. DOBLE CLICK EN LA IMAGEN DEL +ROJO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. DOBLE CLICK EN LA IMAGEN DEL +AZUL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utiliza la propiedad `Tag` de cada `DataGridViewCell`. Puedes usarla para añadir un texto cuando le asignas el `Value`, y leerla posteriormente para obtener el texto previamente almacenado

Comment: Pikoh porfavor si podría realizar un ejemplo de cómo debería hacerlo te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: puede encontrar la solución gracias a tu consejo Pikoh, muchas gracias.
Como dijiste le asigne una etiqueta a la casilla y de esta manera ya puedo identificar a cada celda.

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Columna1"].Tag = "masRojo";

con este código lo asigne la etiqueta y el lugar de llamarlo con el .Value cambie a .Tag 

dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Tag.ToString()

y me funciono tal como lo necesitaba.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto :) Para que la pregunta quede respondida, deberías añadir una respuesta con el código que has usado y una pequeña explicación a ser posible.